# leaks in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've got 4 tab bars where clicking the second tab bar parses the rss feeds and shows in table view. I'm getting a leak something like this in my leaked Blocks as NCFString if I double click it ... I'm getting something like

> +0x86 call    DYLD-STUB$$CFStringCreateWithBytes

... I have no clue ... Will apple rejects app thats has got 1 or 2 leaks ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes they will surely reject you app even for a single leak....

You might think I might be joking but is absolute a joke lol :)

Apple won't reject you app until it crashes. If your memory leaks are lager that causes your application to crash that may be the problem. But if you are having the leaks of just in KBs or even in some MBs I think that's OK only if you are not able to fix that.

Comment: dude seriously..thought of kicking ur butt..on reading the first two lines...later..nah..i ll forgive u...lol

Answer (score 1):

will apple reject app thats has got 1 or 2 leaks? - NO.
As far as your game didn't exit while testing it won't get rejected.